# Use widgets on Desktop Lion

Tags: macos, widgets, dashboard

How can I use my widgets on the desktop in Lion? I have done

```
defaults write com.apple.dashboard demoed yes
```

But, when I click and hold and hit dashboard, it stays on the dashboard. How can I use widgets on my desktop in Lion? @Nathan, how did you do it? I talked to you earlier about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YEah! I found the solution.

Turn Off “Dashboard as a Space”
head to System Preferences > Mission Control. 
Uncheck the “Show Dashboard as a space” box and you’ll have the widgets back.

Then again you can go to terminal en type in:
defaults write com.apple.dashboard devmode YES
hit return/enter
then type in: killall Dock (mind the capital D in Dock)
That's it!